# What are Mozilla Labs' Jetpack IO capabilities?

Tags: io, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Are you able to access your file-system, using Jetpack, and do operations such as creating or reading files or saving images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Add-on SDK 1.0b5 (the most recent version at this moment) has a [file module](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b5/docs/packages/api-utils/docs/file.html) for this purpose. Note that it's [not a high-level module](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b5/docs/dev-guide/module-development/about.html), meaning it can change incompatibly in future Add-on SDK versions.

[the original answer from 2010/01]
*No, there's no jetpack-specific APIs for this yet, note the red link on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Jetpack/Storage) and the [lack of a "JEP" about this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Jetpack/JEPs). You're not prevented from using [normal Mozilla APIs for file I/O](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO) (yet?), though.*

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, Nickolay, you're wrong. See [file](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/0.9/docs/#module/jetpack-core/file) documentation.

---

Comment: Old information. Look at the date at which this was asked and answered.